# ValidationError [SequelizeValidationError]: Validation error: Invalid validator function: nonEmpty,

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying Sequelize.js for the first time and I don't know what's the error. I am using Oath2 for Google login and sending the user data to MySQL localhost server:

Error

> ValidationError [SequelizeValidationError]: Validation error: Invalid validator function: nonEmpty,
> Validation error: Invalid validator function: nonEmpty,
> Validation error: Invalid validator function: nonEmpty
> at InstanceValidator._validate (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:78:13)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> at async InstanceValidator._validateAndRunHooks (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:111:7)
> at async InstanceValidator.validate (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:93:12)
> at async model.save (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:3877:7)
> at async Function.create (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2207:12) {
> errors: [
> ValidationErrorItem {
> message: 'Invalid validator function: nonEmpty',
> type: 'Validation error',
> path: 'name',
> value: 'Ravikant Chaudhary',
> origin: 'FUNCTION',
> instance: [User],
> validatorKey: null,
> validatorName: null,
> validatorArgs: [],
> original: Error: Invalid validator function: nonEmpty
> at InstanceValidator._invokeBuiltinValidator (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:300:13)
> at F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:222:37
> at F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4925:15
> at Function.forIn (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:12976:11)
> at InstanceValidator._singleAttrValidate (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:198:7)
> at F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:148:30
> at F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4925:15
> at Function.forIn (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:12976:11)
> at InstanceValidator._perAttributeValidators (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:131:7)          at InstanceValidator._validate (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:73:12)
> },
> ValidationErrorItem {
> message: 'Invalid validator function: nonEmpty',
> type: 'Validation error',
> path: 'email',
> value: 'ravikc1799@gmail.com',
> origin: 'FUNCTION',
> instance: [User],
> validatorKey: null,
> validatorName: null,
> validatorArgs: [],
> original: Error: Invalid validator function: nonEmpty
> at InstanceValidator._invokeBuiltinValidator (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:300:13)
> at F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:222:37
> at F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4925:15
> at Function.forIn (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:12976:11)
> at InstanceValidator._singleAttrValidate (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:198:7)
> at F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:148:30
> at F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4925:15
> at Function.forIn (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:12976:11)
> at InstanceValidator._perAttributeValidators (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:131:7)          at InstanceValidator._validate (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:73:12)
> },
> ValidationErrorItem {
> message: 'Invalid validator function: nonEmpty',
> type: 'Validation error',
> path: 'googleId',
> value: '105642570429787261091',
> origin: 'FUNCTION',
> instance: [User],
> validatorKey: null,
> validatorName: null,
> validatorArgs: [],
> original: Error: Invalid validator function: nonEmpty
> at InstanceValidator._invokeBuiltinValidator (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:300:13)
> at F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:222:37
> at F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4925:15
> at Function.forIn (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:12976:11)
> at InstanceValidator._singleAttrValidate (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:198:7)
> at F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:148:30
> at F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4925:15
> at Function.forIn (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:12976:11)
> at InstanceValidator._perAttributeValidators (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:131:7)          at InstanceValidator._validate (F:\Web Development\YT\Ytube\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:73:12)
> }
> ]
> }

**index.js**

```
   const cors = require('cors')

   const app = express()

const db = require('./models');
const { User } = require('./models');

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors());


app.post("/signin", (req, res) => {
   const name = req.body.name
   const email = req.body.email
   const googleId = req.body.googleId

   User.create({
       name: name,
       email: email,
       googleId: googleId
   }).catch((err) => {
       console.log(err);
   });

   res.send('inserted into database')
})


const PORT = 5000

db.sequelize.sync().then((req) => {
   app.listen(PORT, () => {
       console.log(`node server started at port : ${PORT}`)
   });
});
```

**model**

```
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
    const User = sequelize.define("User", {
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                nonEmpty: true
            }
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                nonEmpty: true
            }
        },
        googleId: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                nonEmpty: true
            }
        }
    });

    return User;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should correct the name of the validation, it should be `notEmpty` and not `nonEmpty`:

```
name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                notEmpty: true
            }
        }
```

See **Per-attribute validations** in [Validations and constraints](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html)

Comment: Oh my God, Thank you so much. Such a silly mistake, I didn't even crosscheck. Thanks a lot.